# Firebase with Angular: exclude field from query

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase

I would like to know if my structure is usable with firebase or do I need to change. Here is one example with /rooms which contain an array of Room:

```
export class Room {
    id: number;
    password: string;
    state: number;
    messages: Message[] = [];
}
```

And Message:

```
export class Message{
    author: string;
    message: string;
    playerExcluded: string;

}
```

Now I have to load a room without password (I guess this part is possible ?) AND where message.playerExcluded != firebase.auth().currentUser.uid (looks harder).

It means each user will have all message except message where they are excluded. 
One solution could be to load fields without objects from Room (like id, state), and then another query for loading Message but this doesn't seem optimal.

Possible or too complicated in one query? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Firebase documentation, you should [flatten your data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data), and since you are already doing that, your structure should be okay. This also means that you will need to perform **two** queries to get the messages.

---

From the Firebase documentation:

> If the data is instead split into separate paths, also called denormalization, it can be efficiently downloaded in separate calls, as it is needed. Consider this flattened structure:

```
{
  // Chats contains only meta info about each conversation
  // stored under the chats's unique ID
  "chats": {
    "one": {
      "title": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
      "lastMessage": "ghopper: Relay malfunction found. Cause: moth.",
      "timestamp": 1459361875666
    },
    "two": { ... },
    "three": { ... }
  },

  // Conversation members are easily accessible
  // and stored by chat conversation ID
  "members": {
    // we'll talk about indices like this below
    "one": {
      "ghopper": true,
      "alovelace": true,
      "eclarke": true
    },
    "two": { ... },
    "three": { ... }
  },

  // Messages are separate from data we may want to iterate quickly
  // but still easily paginated and queried, and organized by chat
  // conversation ID
  "messages": {
    "one": {
      "m1": {
        "name": "eclarke",
        "message": "The relay seems to be malfunctioning.",
        "timestamp": 1459361875337
      },
      "m2": { ... },
      "m3": { ... }
    },
    "two": { ... },
    "three": { ... }
  }
}
```

Also from the documentation:

> It's now possible to iterate through the list of rooms by downloading only a few bytes per conversation, quickly fetching metadata for listing or displaying rooms in a UI. Messages can be fetched separately and displayed as they arrive, allowing the UI to stay responsive and fast.

Comment: Thank's for your answer Isaac, I guess your answer to my principal question is no. This doesn't answer all my questions but I review my structure !